# Image resizing without blurriness

Tags: html, css, image, web, jpeg

Making a new banner for a website- problem is that the website dimensions are 920w x 174H. My jpg is 2892w x 499H. which is larger but no matter what it comes in smaller on the page so, I have to enlarge it manually- that makes to pic blurry. How do I get it in the correct size so I don't have a blurry pic?

Comment: Please include the code in your question.

Comment: If the website displays the banner at 920x174px, why not create a jpeg of that size so no browser needs to do resizing and cause blurry pictures?

Comment: I did but it doesnt load on the site as that size so im always having to manually do it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `img` markup for the banner including the `width=` or `height=` parameters?  Or is there a CSS style setting them?  Examples:

```
<img src="img_banner.jpg"  width="500" height="600">
<img src="img_banner.jpg"  style="width:500px;height:600px;">
```

If so, that is forcing the web browser to rescale the image to the wrong size.  You can use a variety of image manipulation programs such as IrfanView or Gimp to resize your new banner to the appropriate size, reupload it to your web server, and then include the appropriate width and height parameters to speed up page rendering.

Comment: Im using the given above code= <div style="width: 500px;height:500px">
<img src="https://preview.ibb.co/hseNjd/the_one.jpg" width="920" height="174">

Comment: My problem is that I have no idea how to redo it to the 920x174 dimensions.

Comment: Download Irfanview at https://www.irfanview.com/, and the following link gives you steps to resize: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/65221/resizing-an-image-using-irfanview/

Comment: can I use photoshop?

Comment: Sure; not familiar with Photoshop but just google "resize image photoshop"

Comment: its not blurry when i open it as a jpeg. I'm so lost.

Comment: Get rid of the `<div style="width: 500px;height:500px">` and see what happens.

Comment: Still blurry. The jpeg is the same size and clear when I open it but when I put the code in its blurry. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Show us your code and the image. Make a snippet to here

Comment: <a href="https://ibb.co/iR2TqJ"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/n25Rcy/banner_18.jpg" alt="banner_18" border="0"></a>

Comment: When I hit http://preview.ibb.co/n25Rcy/banner_18.jpg I get a 640 pixel wide by 124 pixel high image.  If your web page has any CSS styles setting widths, etc. you will be in trouble.  Try creating a copy of the web page in trouble, eliminate everything except the image and enough of the web page that demonstrates the issue, then edit your original question and include the source code of your page. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this css?

```
.img{
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor; // IE 7+ (non-standard property)
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; // Safari 6, UC Browser 9.9
  image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges; // Safari 7+
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; // Firefox 3.6+
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges; // Opera 12
  image-rendering: pixelated; // Chrome 41+ and Opera 26+
}
```